# LaTeX Error: File `foo.ent' not found

Tags: miktex, endnotes

I'm trying to compile the Latex template from [there](http://digra-fdg2016.org/downloads/). The template use the `endnote` packages.

When I compile the document I get this error from `lualatex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `main.ent' not found.
```

Where "main" is my latex filename. From what I've seen, the .ent file is a file linked to the `endnote` package, that I have installed.

Any suggestion?

I'm using MiKTeX on Windows 10.

Comment: I have no problem.

Comment: At first use. I had no problem. But after I removed Auxiliary files (in TeXworks) after that I always recieve the error. And if I make an empty file with that name. I will not receive the errors, but I will not get my endnotes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .ent file seems to be created only if you actually have an endnote (that is, at least one); otherwise you get the error you describe, occurring at the point that the .ent file is to be read in with all the endnotes in it.

Best would be if the package either generated an empty file, when there are no endnotes, or checked for the file before trying to read it.

A workaround is to stick in a dummy "just in case" endnote, thus making sure there's at least one.

Comment: dummy file is just a pain killer, you will not get the endotes. At least in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `\IfFileExists` command you could also make the endnotes conditional, e.g.:

```
\IfFileExists{\jobname.ent}{
   \theendnotes
}{
   %no endnotes
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  One could make this slightly more flexible by replacing `./main.ent` by `\jobname.int`, which is the same file as `\theendnotes` looks for.